# Question about Modular function in Haar measure

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

I'm reading the book "Basic Lie Theory"
(http://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/abbaspou/Lie-Book_verrouille.pdf)
and I'm trying to understand the proof of Lemma 2.3.4 which states that:

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $H$ be a closed subgroup, $\Delta_G$ and $\Delta_H$ be the Haar measure of $G$ and $H$ respectively and $I(f)(g) := \int_H f(gh)dh$.
Suppose $\Delta_G |_H = \Delta_H$. Let $f \in C_0(G)$. If $I(f) = 0$, then $\int_G f(g)dg = 0$.

Most of the proof are alright except I don't understand where the equality
\begin{equation}
\int_G f(g) \int_H \phi(gh^{-1})\Delta_G(h)dhdg = \int_G f(g) \int_H \phi(gh) \Delta_H(h^{-1})\Delta_G(h) dhdg
\end{equation}
came from. I feel that the RHS should be equals to $\int_G f(g) \int_H \phi(g) dhdg$ which doesn't look like the LHS. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: See Julian Rosen's answer here about why precomposing with the inverse map is the same as integrating against the modular function. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575894/equation-involving-the-integral-of-the-modular-function-of-a-topological-group

Comment: So that's one of the thing I never understood as well, why is $\Delta_G(x) dx^{-1}$ a left Haar measure? Do I have to show that $\int_G f((g^{-1}x)^{-1}) \Delta_G(x^{-1}) dx = \int_G f(x^{-1}) \Delta_G(x^{-1}) dx$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you have to show.